# Can form entries from a WordPress form go to a database

Tags: php, database

I am using Wordpress 4.3.1.

I have built a stand alone form (form 1) using PHP where one can enter volunteering tasks doable in a city, has fields like volunteering activity, city, state. The values submitted using this form will become data for another form (form 2). Using form 2, someone else who is searching for volunteering tasks can find it. So, if in form 1, I enter, that you can volunteer in Animal Shelter in  Atlanta, Georgia it goes to a back-end database. Later, if someone is using form 2 and searches for volunteering activities in Atlanta, Georgia, they should get a result like volunteer in Animal Shelter in Atlanta, Georgia.

I realize form 1's data can be stored in a back-end database which can be source for form 2 searches.

1. Are there any plug-ins in WordPress which do it? If so, which are they?
2. If not, how can I integrate the two forms built in PHP into the current WordPress theme Salient so that the forms
   don't look separate from the website?
3. Are there any frameworks which can speed up the building of form 2?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress supports Custom Post types, because this isn't just about the form, but about displaying the data and making it searchable by other users - https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

I would recommend you look up http://pods.io/ which would help create these custom post types also build relationships between two post types (or Pods as they call it). Also there is an option for visitors to enter the data using frontend forms.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I am sorry for the delayed response. Can using the Pods plugin allow users/visitors to enter data using frontend forms? I appreciate your advice and time.

Comment: Yes, you can create frontend forms - http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/form/